# Anyone know how to write bengali or hindi?

Tags: ibus, input-language, internationalization

I have tried installing `banglaword` using `wine` which did not worked at all.

I have tied using layouts but i feel it is too hard to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

For bengali you can use avro phonetic.

**Method 1**

Using `ibus` as input method, you can try with avro m17n package.It works like charm. You can download from [here](https://github.com/avro-phonetic/Avro-Phonetic-m17n)

- Download the latest dev file, install it.(Read the instruction in `README` and `Install.txt`)
- Install `ibus-m17n` from software center.
- Switch input method to ibus and configure ibus like this. You can also install hindi from here. (I never tried)
- Log out and login. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>space</kbd> to switch input methods. To change keyboard shortcut, use `General` tab of the shown picture.

[image: Configure input methods]

**Method 2**

Traditionally avro is instructed to setup with `scim` input method. But it doesn't work well in latest ubuntu version (>= 11.10). A ppa package is available (tutorial [here](http://kaustav.codebinders.com/2011/05/install-avro-phonetic-scim-avro-in-ubuntu-from-ppa.html)) also or can compile for [source](http://code.google.com/p/scim-avro/).

Comment: When Im trying to install avro-phonetic it displays a warning "The package is of bad quality: The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation who provided this package file and include the details beneath." Should i ignore this warning ? I have scim-avro installed. I installed ibus-m17n. Do I need to remove scim-avro ?

Comment: yes you need to remove scim-avro and also you can ignore the warning.